# Detect Collision with Programmatically Created ImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, collision-detection

In `viewDidLoad` I'm programmatically creating 13 blocks using the code:

```
for (int X = 1; X <= 13; X++) {
    UIImageView *iceBlockX = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((28 * X - 4),52,28,28)];
    iceBlockX.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iceBlock.png"];

    iceBlockX.tag = X;

    [self.view insertSubview:iceBlockX belowSubview:_topPenguinCollisionTarget];
}
```

I need to detect a collision between an imageView created on the storyboard (penguin) and any one programmatically-created imageView block.  If this is possible, what is the code used for the detection?  I've tried the following code, but it's not working:

```
if (((CGRectIntersectsRect(_penguin.frame, _iceBlock1.frame)) && (_iceBlock1.hidden == NO)) ||
     ((CGRectIntersectsRect(_penguin.frame, _iceBlock2.frame)) &&(_iceBlock2.hidden == NO)) ||
     ((CGRectIntersectsRect(_penguin.frame, _iceBlock3.frame)) &&  (_iceBlock3.hidden == NO)) ||
     ((CGRectIntersectsRect(_penguin.frame, _iceBlock4.frame)) && (_iceBlock4.hidden == NO)) ||
     ((CGRectIntersectsRect(_penguin.frame, _iceBlock5.frame)) &&(_iceBlock5.hidden == NO)) ||
     ((CGRectIntersectsRect(_penguin.frame, _iceBlock6.frame)) && (_iceBlock6.hidden == NO)) || 
     ((CGRectIntersectsRect(_penguin.frame, _iceBlock7.frame)) && (_iceBlock7.hidden == NO)) || 
     ((CGRectIntersectsRect(_penguin.frame, _iceBlock8.frame)) && (_iceBlock8.hidden == NO)) || 
     ((CGRectIntersectsRect(_penguin.frame, _iceBlock9.frame)) && (_iceBlock9.hidden == NO)) || 
     ((CGRectIntersectsRect(_penguin.frame, _iceBlock10.frame)) && (_iceBlock10.hidden == NO)) ||
     ((CGRectIntersectsRect(_penguin.frame, _iceBlock11.frame)) && (_iceBlock11.hidden == NO)) ||
     ((CGRectIntersectsRect(_penguin.frame, _iceBlock12.frame)) && (_iceBlock12.hidden == NO)) ||
     ((CGRectIntersectsRect(_penguin.frame, _iceBlock13.frame)) &&(_iceBlock13.hidden == NO))) 
     {
    NSLog(@"A collision was detected");
}
```

Comment: Are you using UIKitDynamics

Comment: I am not using UIKitDynamics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGRectIntersectsRect return true if "rect1" intersects "rect2", else false.

```
- (BOOL)didUIImageCollided{
  for (int X = 1; X <= 13; X++)
   {
     UIImageView *iceBlockX = (UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:X];
     if(CGRectIntersectsRect(_penguin.frame, iceBlockX.frame))
     {
              return YES;
     }
  }
  return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for getting me pointed in the right direction.  However,(BOOL)didUIImageCollided appears not be be a valid Xcode command.  But I was able to use the for loop and "UIImageView *iceBlocX ...." code to generate a collision detection.  Finally, instead of "return YES", I substituted code for handling the collision (and did not need to use "return NO").  Again, thanks.

Comment: -(BOOL)didUIImageCollided is method i created to detect collision! well can you accept the answer!?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that fact initially.  I can accept your answer, but can't up-vote you, as my reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: Done (I think).